# Collision detection Libgdx rectangles

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, game-physics

I'm trying to implement Collision detection using Rectangles for my game but can't seem to get it to work.

Bullets are updated when pressing space every frame so they move across the screen. Apparently so I've been told on here, the collisionbox moves with it as well. I'm getting this by using `sprite.getBoundingBox()` which sets a datafield Rectangle to this value for each instance.

I have two Arraylists, one holding instances of Monsters and one holding instances of Bullets. They all have collisionRectangles associated with them.

I'm calling the `checkCollisions()` method from my main render loop every frame as long as there's something in the bullets or monsters arraylist.

```
/*this handles collisions between bullets and enemies*/
public static void checkCollisions(){
    for (int i = 0; i < Main.currentBullets.size(); i++){
        for (int k = 0; k < Main.currentMonsters.size(); k++){
            if (Intersector.overlaps(Main.currentBullets.get(i).collisionBoxBullet,
                  Main.currentMonsters.get(k).collisionBoxMonster)){
                     System.out.println("Boom headshot");
                }
        }
    }
```

Shouldn't this do Boom Headshot every time it overlaps? Instead it always seems to keep evaluating to true.

Why does it keep evaluating to true and writing boom headshot?

Comment: The method `sprite.getBoundingRectangle()` does create a `BoundingRectangle` for the `Sprite`. That means, that it is not a reference, which is updated, when you move the `Sprite`. So to keep the `collisionBoxBullet` and `collisionBoxMonster` up to date you need to call `sprite.getBoundingRectangle` every frame.  Also make sure, that the `Bullet`s and `Monster`s are not to fast, so that they don't "tunnel" through each other!

Comment: Great thanks, I am updating the bounding rectangle every time but still it's always saying "boom headshot" and evaluating for true. Why is this if conditional evaluating to true?

Comment: Thats hard to tell... Try a `System.out.println()` before the `if`-condition and print the 2 `collisionBox`es out. Then show me the results of a few checks, not only one.

Answer (score 0):

What I didn't do is set the position of the rectangle of the sprite which was at 0.0. I also then didn't   move the collision box properly with `collisionBox.setPosition()`.

It initially checking to see if sprite at 0/0 is colliding with collision box at 0.0 which is always true, hence always saying it's overlapping.